# Offline Firestore : Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am getting those error messages when I am using my App offline (it is working when I am online):

> W/Firestore(23675): (24.0.1) [WatchStream]: (da69cba) Stream closed
> with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=End of stream or
> IOException, cause=null}. W/Firestore(23675): (24.0.1) [WriteStream]:
> (9780b0d) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE,
> description=End of stream or IOException, cause=null}.
> W/Firestore(23675): (24.0.1) [WriteStream]: (9780b0d) Stream closed
> with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve
> host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
> "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

Here is my main.dart :

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
```

What did I miss ? (I have the last version of flutter and cloud_firestore package)

Is it because I am in debug mode using Android Emulator ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#access-data-offline), offline persistence of data is enabled by default. Does the application crash or stop working when it’s offline?

Comment: None of them, but it never stop loading/waiting and the next action is not executed :(

Answer (score 1):

It could be a server error or it could be related to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3302).

As you can see the issue on Github is still open and under investigation, if you can update to the latest version of flutter.

For the `UNAVAILABLE` Firebase ErrorCode documentation says:

```
UNAVAILABLE (HTTP error code = 503) The server is overloaded.   The server couldn't process the request in time. Retry the same request, but you must:
- Honor the Retry-After header if it is included in the response from the FCM Connection Server.
- Implement exponential back-off in your retry mechanism. (e.g. if you waited one second before the first retry, wait at least two second before the next one, then 4 seconds and so on). If you're sending multiple messages, delay each one independently by an additional random amount to avoid issuing a new request for all messages at the same time. Senders that cause problems risk being denylisted.
```

[Check here for more about Error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode)

Also,basic but worth a test, make sure that the device connection is stable with no drops.

Comment: I well have the last version of flutter. Firestore is supposed to work offline, then it should handle connection drops, no ?

Comment: You have to configure it correctly first and specify to fetch data from the cache. More info in docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline